# Практика ведения историчных таблиц в web приложении

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Всем привет!

Разрабатываю web-приложения на Django. Заказчик хочет вести историю изменения таблиц в отдельных таблицах с постфиксом _HIST.
Допустим есть таблица CARS с полями CAR_ID, CAR_NAME. Допустим в ней была запись:

> CAR_ID = 1, CAR_NAME = 'BMW'

. На запись сделали DELETE where CAR_ID = 1. И в _HIST должна появиться запись:

> CAR_ID = 1, CAR_NAME = 'BMW', EFF_FROM_DT = 1900-01-01, EFF_TO_DT =
> current_date

.

Планирую реализовать это через триггеры Postgres.

Вопрос: Раньше в приложениях не видел практики ведения таких таблиц, может есть какие-то глобальные причины использования такого подхода?

Comment: Какого именно «такого» подхода? С таблицами истории или без?

Comment: С таблицами истории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне нормальная практика, для БД, имеющих хоть какое-то отношение к деньгам или прочим видам строгой отчётности.

Например, если вы осуществляете продажи, вы обязаны несколько лет (3 или 5, точно не помню), хранить у себя исходящие документы. Достаточно важно, чтоб в случае чего вы могли восстановить названия товаров именно в том виде, в котором отдали клиенту на бумаге.

Если всю историю хранить в одной таблице, то выборка актуальных значений со временем будет замедляться, и это плохо.

Тут есть несколько слегка различающихся подходов к организации именно HIST-таблицы, но общая идея одна. В основной таблице только актуальные данные, а прежние можно вытянуть из HIST